# SendKeys.Send ("%"); does not send "%" symbol

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

SendKeys.Send ("%"); does not send "%" symbol

```
    while (true)
    {
        string a2 = @"%%asdf%%";
        foreach (char a in a2)
        {
              SendKeys.Send(a.ToString());
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: `-1` for no [research effort](https://www.google.com/search?q=sendkeys+percent+sign)

Comment: Now it will be easier to research in the future.

Comment: But this post has 256 viewers for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx):

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}).

`SendKeys.Send` also takes a String.

So why not:

```
string a2 = @"{%}{%}asdf{%}{%}";
SendKeys.Send(a2);
```